# Active directory deployment

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

A new software version has came up and I'm requested to install it on numerous machines and I have been wondering about deploying it through GPO so here it is:
If you deploy an MSI through AD does the previous version of it uninstalls ? Or you have to uninstall it manually ?
The machines are windows 10 based and the AD server is running windows 2012 R2.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you _manually_ install the MSI while having an older version installed? That's what happens.

Comment: @grawity it installs and I'll end up having 2 versions .

Comment: The previous version will only install if your MSI removes the previous version when its ran.  If you want the previous version uninstalled, you have to uninstall it, before the new version is installed.  You can also design your installer, so the "new" version is the same as the "old" version, and all you do just install the program again.  The behavior of the installer is entirely up to you.

Comment: @Ramhound I will give that a shot

Comment: SCCM will be a better channel. I generally don't like GPO deployments, causes a lot of logon performance issue, especially over slow link.

Comment: Actually I have never been able to install sccm no matter how much times I've tried

Comment: Ninite works very well if the application is on their list. https://ninite.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved by Uninstalling previous version using WMIC that I ran remotely on the computers:

```
WMIC product where "name='Your software name here'" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

Then I deployed the MSI as usually through GPO `Computer Configuration > Policies > Software Settings > Software installation`  and everything went smoothly.